# MySQL query very slow on live db but fast locally and on staging?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, query-optimization, database-performance

execution time

- local : 0.0097 seconds
- prod : 10 seconds

local and prod have exactly the same amount and value of data

this is my server specification

- 16 VCPUS / 32 GB RAM / 200 GB SSD Disk

ofcourse, my local and staging are lower than server specifiaction

List below shows what i already checked and did

1. cpu : cpu utilization is in good condition only used 20%-25%.
2. memory: still have a lot of memory available.
3. db optimization :we did the db optimization but only improves 2 seconds.
4. query execution: local only took 0.0097 to processed my query so i guess my query is good to go

What else should i check?

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your query, your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question. This sort of thing often relates to the use of indexes.

Comment: Similar number of rows?  No extra network latency?

Answer (score 3):

You may try the following:

1. Explain you sql in prod and local, check whether the output is the same.
2. Check the running threads, to see if there are difference between prod and local: SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST;
3. Check if there is lock blocking your sql: SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS